# why define android activity result_ok -1

Tags: android, android-activity

```
 /** Standard activity result: operation succeeded. */
    public static final int RESULT_OK           = -1;
```

why define RESULT_OK -1 in android activity,not 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for why "-1" was chosen, one can only guess.  My best guess is that Android is trying to ensure that RESULT_OK does not collide with user-defined constants.  That is, when you develop an Activity and define your own response codes, you would likely chose positive integer values.  If RESULT_OK was "1", then there is a higher probability that an app developer might chose that as well.

Just my theory.