# Take photo via intent returns -1 as result code

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-fileprovider

My goal is to take a picture via a camera app and save it to a directory. Much like this tutorial explains: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

However, onActivityResult returns -1 as return code on some devices. 
The problem is most likely that the camera app cannot write the photo file to the URI I provide but I don't understand why.

Here are my tests results:

- Moto G with Android 7: works fine
- Xiaomi Mi A1 with Android 7.1: fails
- Samsung Galaxy A40 with Android 9: fails

Here's what I do:

Declare provider in the manifest (along with the proper permisions)

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mypackage.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>
```

Declare a proper file path

```
    <paths>
        <external-path name="my_images"  path="Android/data/com.mypackage/files/Pictures" />
    </paths>
```

In the activity, launch the camera app with an intent

```
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->

            takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(requireContext().packageManager)?.also {

                val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.FRANCE).format(Date())

                requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)?.let { storageDir ->

                    File.createTempFile("JPEG_${timeStamp}_", ".jpg", storageDir).also {

                        fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(), "com.mypackage.fileprovider", it)
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri)
                        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_PIC_CODE)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Instead of **external-path**, try **<external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />**

Comment: @AlexCohn  I still have the same issue with <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />

Comment: Wait a sec… [`RESULT_OK == -1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26199510/192373) ‼

Comment: You're right, well done :). My problem is not because resultCode is equal to -1. It is because resultData is null. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890757/android-camera-data-intent-returns-null helped me with this null resultData. You put me on the right track. I would accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, resultData: Intent?)
```

When *`onActivityResult` returns `-1` as return code*, you are actually very lucky: **`-1`** is nothing but [Activity.RESULT_OK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#RESULT_OK). Actually, with **ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE** intent, you don't care what the return code is; it's enough to check whether the temp file you opened in **storageDir** is not empty (an empty file is created in your app, and the image is stored there by a Camera app).

This said, I advice to use `<external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />`, to be less dependent on the implementation details of [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)).

If your activity has only one call to `startActivityForResult()`, you don't need to even check the **requestCode**.

Finally, in your scenario, **requestData** will probably be [null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10779050/192373). This parameter is only relevant when your **ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE** intent does not specify `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Luckily, you need no information that **requestData** Intent could pass to you.